# How can we add custom template in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

[image]

I would like to add some custom tabs(template) in my keycloak? But i cant find the solution. Is anyone here who could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot suggest that you are still using the old account console. I recommend to upgrade to the new account console which supports adding additional tabs quite easily. Take a look at [this blog post](https://www.keycloak.org/2020/09/new-account-console.adoc.html) for details and check out this [quickstart example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/extend-account-console) to get going.